# How To Flip / Reverse A Row Of Data in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

**Raw Data:**

```
abc|bcd|def|efg
dfg|sjd|dss
sdj|sdr|xyz|djh|sfd
```

**Expected Data like**

```
efg|def|bcd|abc
dss|sjd|dfg
sfd|djh|xyz|sdr|sdj
```

Comment: Is there a maximum number of | per line?

Comment: Dumping it into Excel/Google sheets would probably be easier

Comment: You'd better write a small script in your favorite scripting language

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite Number of `|` per line you can fill the Lines up by replacing

`^(.*)$` with `$1|000|000|000|000|000`

switch the values by replacing

`^(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)` with `$5|$4|$3|$2|$1`

and remove the extra `000`s by replacing `\|?000\|?` with nothing